# Where can I find the installed package path via brew

Tags: macos, homebrew

I installed some packages via brew. But I can not find where they are.

I can **not** get access by typing `hping` on terminal

```
% brew install hping
(git)-[master] 
Warning: hping-3.20051105 already installed
```

Comment: My hping is installed in `/usr/local/Cellar/hping/3.20051105/sbin/hping`

Comment: I had the same problem with `daemonize`, [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/324616/how-should-i-set-the-path-variable-on-my-mac-so-the-hombrew-installed-tools-are) helped me understand that daemonize is installed in `/usr/local/sbin` that was not in the PATH

Answer (score 297):

Use the following to show the installation path of a package:

```
brew info hping
```

Example output:

```
pcre: stable 8.35 (bottled)
http://www.pcre.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.35 (146 files, 5.8M) *
  Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/pcre.rb
==> Options
--universal
    Build a universal binary
```

Comment: Is it possible to get only path? In my case I want to use clang from llvm and after "brew install llvm" clang is still apple's, but one from llvm binaries is what I need.

Comment: BTW `brew doctor` might help you understand issues as well.

Comment: @okutane You would need to assemble the path yourself. As a crude example, you could do `echo "$(brew --cellar llvm)/$(brew list --versions llvm | tr ' ' '\n' | tail -1)/bin/clang"`

Comment: Depending on your specific needs, `brew --prefix hping` (from @capripot's answer) may do the trick.

Comment: Usually brew stores symlinks to the latest bin in `/usr/local/bin/`

Comment: ^ although note that on M1 Macs, they live in `/opt/homebrew/bin/`

Answer (score 59):

To figure out where your formula is installed, do
`brew --prefix hping`

You can also relink your `hping` binary by doing `brew unlink hping && brew link hping`

Also maybe your `$PATH` is not well defined. Does the list given by `echo $PATH` contains the result given by `echo $(brew --prefix)'/bin:'$(brew --prefix)'/sbin'`? This path should be toward the beginning of the list to be prioritized over system binaries, surely before `/usr/bin`.

To do so, you can add this at the end of your `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=$(brew --prefix)/bin:$(brew --prefix)/sbin:$PATH
```

As a result, after opening a new terminal or doing `source ~/.zshrc`, you'll be able to echo your correct path as:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: Thank you, `brew --prefix <command>` was exactly what I needed.

Comment: This does not work for "cask" packages.

Comment: I used the hint here to resolve a dependency against Postgres on an M1 w/Monterey. This, plus `brew info package` as mentioned above, and this FAQ, cleared things up for me: https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-is-the-default-installation-prefix-opthomebrew-on-apple-silicon

Answer (score 40):

`brew --cellar` prints the directory which is the default location on macOS. You'll see sub-directories in there for all your installed formulae.

Answer (score 11):

Try this command

```
brew --cellar <FORMULA>
```

e.g.

```
brew --cellar hping
```

Comment: Alternatively, `brew --prefix hping` may be helpful as well.

Comment: Thanks heaps. This doesn't seem to work for casks. Any idea?

Answer (score 10):

Normally, `homebrew` installs packages into `/usr/local/bin`. So you need to check that your PATH contains that directory, like this:

```
echo $PATH
```

Also, try running

```
brew doctor
```

to make sure your setup is correct. If `/usr/local/bin` is not in your PATH, you need to edit `~/.profile` and add a line like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Then start a new Terminal (in order to re-read your login profile) and try again.

If all that fails, it must be installed somewhere else. You can search for it by running a command like this:

```
sudo find / -name hping -type f
```

Comment: These are symlinks. The actual packages are in `/usr/local/Cellar` as @PapaStanley points out.

Comment: @Steve why is it then that when i do `ls -ld /usr/local/bin` it looks like a regular directory?

Comment: @barlop Because not `/usr/local/bin` is a symlink, the files inside that directory placed there by Brew are symlinks.

Answer (score 7):

Inspired by @RubenLaguna, I came up with this to get the full path to the installed version of the default formula.

As shown in previous answers, to get the install path for a formula:

```sh
brew --prefix nmap
```

Returns a *symlink* to the install path:

```perl
/usr/local/opt/nmap
```

To expand the full path:

```bsh
readlink -f $(brew --prefix nmap)
```

```perl
/usr/local/Cellar/nmap/7.92
```

Answer (score 4):

To find your base installation directory for Homebrew, use one of the following commands:

```bsh
brew --prefix
brew --cellar
```

The latter specifically returns the path of your `Cellar` folder.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find any direct CLI option in `brew` to get the full path to the currently installed **version** of a formula but this would work as long as you are using bash:

```
echo $(brew --cellar asciidoctor)/$(brew info --json asciidoctor | jq -r '.[0].installed[0].version')
# /usr/local/Cellar/asciidoctor/1.5.8
```

Comment: This is not entirely correct if you have more than one version installed in the Cellar.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend adding the following line to your `~/.bash_profile` (or the equivalent configuration file if you are using a different shell):

```
export HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS="--appdir=/Applications"
```

Answer (score 1):

hping requires root privileges to run.

You probably need to add /usr/local/sbin to your PATH.

When I ran brew doctor:

```
Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have installed
formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.
Consider setting the PATH for example like so
    echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that lands here after googling, and/or for anyone who wants a list of packages that are installed as keg only, you can get this info from the `brew` JSON output.

List all installed packages:

```
brew info --json --installed
```

List keg only packages (`jq` tool required):

```
brew info --json --installed | jq -r '.[] | select(.keg_only == true) | .name'
```

List the path for keg only packages (again, `jq` tool required):

```
brew info --json --installed | jq -r '.[] | select(.keg_only == true) | .name' | while read name; do brew --prefix $name; done
```

Answer (score 1):

### The real path to the directory containing versioned directories of the formula

```
brew --cellar <FORMULA>
```

##### Example

```
% brew --cellar spdlog            
/usr/local/Cellar/spdlog
```

### Symlink to the current version of the formula (shorter)

This is what you want most of the time.

```
brew --prefix <FORMULA>
```

##### Example

```
% brew --prefix spdlog         
/usr/local/opt/spdlog
```

Answer (score 0):

> I installed some packages via brew. But I can not find where they are.

It seems that homebrew requires one to be explicit with things.  Fortunately, a bit of escaping using **`brew --prefix`** can make this a no-brainer, for those who need to find the path for the pkg-config utility, e.g.

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=`brew --prefix hping`/lib/pkgconfig/ pkg-config --cflags hping
```

(Except this isn't going to work anyway, because it seems hping doesn't come with hping.pc .. although, in the case where package maintainers do put .pc files, this trick can be useful.)

Answer (score 0):

If someone looking for real path of package:

In my case `brew --cellar opencv3` gives `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv`

But `find /usr/local/Cellar/ -type d -name "*opencv*" -maxdepth 1` gives

`/usr/local/Cellar//opencv3`(which is `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3` actually).

Headers:

`/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.4.1_1/include/`

Libs:

`/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.4.1_1/lib/`

Answer (score -1):

```
brew list opencv
```

Output like this:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/bin/opencv_annotation
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/bin/opencv_interactive-calibration
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/bin/opencv_model_diagnostics
...
```

My brew version:

```
brew -v
> Homebrew 3.2.1
```

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: @nohillside List all installed formulae and casks. If formula is provided, summarise the paths within its current keg. If cask is provided, list its artifacts.